# 'no rule to make target' with no reason

Tags: linux, makefile

I was installing this program: [THERMUS](http://www.phy.uct.ac.za/people/wheaton/THERMUS/thermus_index.html), that, as i know should install fine. I/m installing this program through ubuntu console. But when i run `make all` i got this message:

> `make: ***No rule to make target '/main/TTMParticle.h', needed by 'BQConstrainQ.o'. Stop.`

I know that it could be caused by the fact that file TTMParticle.h doesn't exist in /main/, but i checked - it's there.

Comment: Do you mean `$PWD/main/TTMParticle.h`? Because that's not the same as `/main/TTMParticle.h`. This sounds like a variable the makefile expects to have a value that is failing to do so for some reason or something like that.

Comment: Actually, having just looked at the `THERMUS` download page it looks like you just failed to set the `THERMUS` environment variable. Though requiring that is a bit of a disastrous makefile paradigm for something as simple as this (when a default value would work just fine).

Comment: @EtanReisner: or the variable is `THERMUS` set but not exported. I suppose you wrote this comment at the moment that I entered the answer below...

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek Yup, looks like it. Though I'm not sure the variable needs exporting since only it looks like (again quick look) like only make needs to see the value of that variable.

Comment: @EtanReisner You're right, i failed to set environment variable. I've tried this:
`THERMUS="/home/user/THERMUS/"'
export THERMUS
cd /home/user/THERMUS/main/
make all`

But this gave me a lot of errors.

Comment: @mtrn That's entirely possible if other things are not set up the way it expects. The build process for `THERMUS` seems exceptionally obtuse and complicated from the few minutes I looked at it. I'd accept @ReinierTorenbeek's answer and post a new question with the other errors (if you want help with them).

Answer (score 1):

Your environment variable `THERMUS` is not properly set. The [build instructions](http://www.phy.uct.ac.za/people/wheaton/THERMUS/SourceDownload.html) mention:

> 3 .  Set an environment variable `THERMUS' to point at the top-level
>   directory containing the THERMUS code

It does not mention that you have to do `export THERMUS` to make that variable available to other processes, like `make`, so you might have forgotten that -- or not have set `THERMUS` at all. Without actually having tried it, I think the fastest way to get rid of this message is to run `make` as follows:

```
THERMUS=.. make all
```

---

To track down the issue, check out the file `functions/makefile` where you problem occurs. It mentions:

```
SEP_CLASSESH    = $(THERMUS)/main/TTMParticle.h \
```

and later contains the dependency

```
$(FNCSO):   $(FNCSS) $(SEP_CLASSESH)
```

which is the line that causes the actual error, because

```
FNCSO           = BQConstrainQ.o \
```